# Session can not be sent from backend to frontend

Tags: git, phpstorm, webstorm, atlassian-sourcetree

I have the issue that I am not getting a session from the backend. My application works on the live server but not on the localhost. I had the same issue before and I was working on it for about 1 week, then I had realized that the problem has nothing to do with my code. So I have played around with Git and used `checkout` to switch to previous versions and that worked! Even if I switched back to my current version, it still worked. I have no idea why and how but I was just glad that it worked. So now I have exactly the same problem again. I have tried the same to checkout previous versions but this time it doesn't work anymore. What is here the problem and how can I fix it?

It has definitely nothing to do with my code since the same code works on my server and it also worked on localhost before.

I am working with Angular (WebStorm) and Symfony (PhpStorm).

I am using Sourcetree. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a watcher (like nodemon node or springloader for ruby) then it is likely to blame. Try restarting your server if you have not already.

Comment: Oh wow, restarting the server was the key. Thank you so much!

Comment: nice. No worries.

Comment: You might consider posting your language and watcher so people know to look out for this happening if they have a similar setup.

Comment: Sure, I have updated my question.